# Is there a way to media-query if the window is taller than it is wide in css? (portrait vs landscape for any devices)

Tags: css, media-queries

Is there a way to media-query if the window is taller than it is wide in CSS? 
A sorta portrait vs landscape for any devices.

I know this is easy enough with javascript but I'm searching for a CSS only solution.

Comment: `max-height` `min-height`  `orientation: landscape`  `orientation: portrait` should do ?

Comment: For some reason, I thought orientation was specific to devices not the viewport. Thx.

Comment: To resolve the question.... `@media (orientation: portrait) { YOUR CSS... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select the devices which has width more than 320 and less than 767 and orientation will be landscape only.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px)and (max-width: 767px)and (orientation: landscape) {}
```

another example of you want to select by height and width combination:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) and (min-height: 400px) and (max-height: 812px) {}
```

althoug better use is using orientation in your case, as per the question